# Perl: No replacement of a string

Tags: string, perl, replace

If i replace a string in another one using something simple like this

```
my $pet = "I have a dog.";
my $search = "dog";
my $replace = "cat";
$pet =~ s/$search/$replace/;
```

it works fine and i get "*I have a cat*." as expected.

But when i am using something more complex like the following it doesn't get replaced:

```
my $image_correction_hash = {};

$device = "my_device";
$correction_hash->{$device}->{'to_be_replaced'} = "174_4492_232313_7078721ec0.jpg";

# my json string
my $json = '[{"credits":[],"issue":174,"layout":"special_cover","text":[],"hide_overline":"","category":"Kunst","id":"174_4492","media_data":[{"thumbnail":"","data_is_cover":1,"subheadline":"","value":"174_4492.jpg","type":"image","headline":""},{"data_position":"left","thumbnail":"","subheadline":"","value":"174_4492_232302_3980b3da34.jpg","data_effect":"smear","type":"image","headline":""},{"data_position":"right","thumbnail":"","subheadline":"","value":"174_4492_232313_7078721ec0.jpg","data_effect":"smear","type":"image","headline":""}],"links":[],"textmarker":"","teaser":"","hide_headline":"","article_thumbnail":"174_4492_article_thumbnail.jpg","subheadline":"","gallery":[],"overline":"","headline":"Covertitel\n"}]';


print STDERR "JSON string before:" . $json . "\n";

foreach my $search ( keys %{$correction_hash->{$device}})
{
    print STDERR "to be replaced:".$correction_hash->{$device}->{$search}.".\n";

    # the replacement
    $json =~ s/$search/XXXXX/g;
}
print STDERR "JSON string after:" . $json . "\n"; # no replacement occured - GRRR
```

**Where is the error here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `$search` in your pattern replacement, not the actual pattern you want to replace. So you're trying to replace `to_be_replaced` with `XXXXXXXX`. Not `174_4492_232313_7078721ec0.jpg`.

You probably want to add:

```
  $replace_pattern = $correction_hash->{$device}->{$search};
  $json =~ s/$replace_pattern/XXXXX/g;
```

Comment: Second pair of eyes will often spot things that you just can't see for looking at.

Comment: absolutly correct - and its already late here so i am not up with perfect wits anymore

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up your variables.

Try this:

```
print STDERR "to be replaced:".$search.".\n";
```

It will print this: `to be replaced:to_be_replaced.`

So you can use this code:

```
my $pattern = $correction_hash->{$device}->{$search};
$json =~ s/$pattern/XXXXX/g;
```

On a side note, if your `$pattern` is not a regex, you should escape it using this code:

```
$json =~ s/\Q$pattern\E/XXXXX/g;
```

Comment: @Thariama Please note the likely need for [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) as recommended by this answer.